# Attempting to save from dataset to database- not working so well

Tags: vb.net, oledbcommand

I have a report, I populate a datatable and dataset- and a couple crystal reports, and those work. I am trying to get my updates from the datatable back to the database- I've seen so much different code all over and I've tried to use it but I think it may have confused me more than helped.

```
  Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnUpdate.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Dim cndl As New OleDbConnection(ConnectionStrings("deputylog").ConnectionString)

    Dim Command = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Case_log.SCRNO, Case_log.JOBNO, Case_log.DEPUTY, Case_log.VICTIM_COMPLAINT, " & _
      "Case_log.TYPE_INVEST, Case_log.WHERE, Case_log.REPORT_DATE, Case_log.ARREST_DATE, Case_log.REPORT_CODES, " & _
      "Case_log.EVIDENCE_SECURED, Case_log.REVIEW_DATE, Case_log.DISP_DATE, Case_log.STATUS, Case_log.SUPP_REPT_DATE ", cndl)
    cndl.Open()
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()


    'adaptor1.UpdateCommand = Command
    MsgBox("Update Successful")
```

The update string is the same as my select string, but I am getting a syntax error when I try to update. Any ideas would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to update 1 row in the database? That statement is not proper SQL syntax for an update statement.

In T-Sql, a basic update statement would be in the format:

```
Update table CASE_LOG set scrno = [some value], deputy = [some value], ...
where id = [some id]
```

In this example, you are updating the case_log table and setting the fields to the supplied values where the id of the row is equal to something that identifies it. In your code you need to format it to this format for sql, here is pseudocode to help you get started:

```
Dim command = New OleDbCommand(string.format("Update Table case_log set scrno = {0}, jobno = {1}, deputy = {2} where id = '[someid]'", scrno.ToString(), jobno.ToString(), deputy.ToString()), cnd1)
```

Comment: So from my datagridview- that value would be what is in that cell correct? Looks like I need to learn how to reference that value.

Comment: Can you add the code for the cell that you are trying to get the value from? Is it a table, datagrid, third party control, other?

Comment: I've made progress- I can now update my column, sadly it updates my column of deputies to '0' but it does update back to the database!